# Why all matrix A times their Nul space/vector get zero space/vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So far, I know a Nul(A) has to pass through the origin, it doesn't have to be a zero vector or space. How A×Nul(A)=[0]?

Answer (score 0):

This is the *definition* of the null space: its vectors are precisely those killed by multiplication by $A$. So if you take a matrix $B$ whose columns form a basis of the null space than all columns of $AB$, which are computed by multiplying individual columns of $B$ (to the left) by $A$, are all zero; probably this is what you mean by $A\times \operatorname{Nul}(A)=[0]$ (I suppose; one does not commonly write the multiplication of a matrix and a subspace).